# How do i skip production deployment in autodevops of gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-autodevops

I am using Gitlab with Auto DevOps on.
I want to use auto devops but with some custom stages on.
I have already written a custom stage and i want to skip production deployment stage.
How can i do it

Answer (score 0):

There is no documented way to skip Production deployment stage.
The other stages can be disabled by adding a variable in the Settings -> CI/CD -> Variables section.

You can find the relevant documentation here:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/autodevops/customize.html#disable-jobs

Or you can enable staging and use a manual production job:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/autodevops/customize.html#deploy-policy-for-staging-and-production-environments

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the `.gitlab-ci.yml` used in AutoDevOps, you can see what you can customize.

The main file is [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Auto-DevOps.gitlab-ci.yml).

The file for the production deploy job is [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Jobs/Deploy.gitlab-ci.yml).

Looking at the production job file, it seems you can disable the production deploy job with a variable, for example, if you manually set `CI_DEPLOY_FREEZE` to `true` (or any value for that matter). You can, also, use a custom `stages` definition (ie, remove the stage called `production` and add you custom deploy stage) or completely overwrite the `production` job.

These are just examples, you should investigate whatever fits best your use case.